# How to speed up the computation of absolute loss matrix in C?

Tags: c, matrix, mex

I am running a Monte-Carlo experiment and evaluate the absolute loss function described below. Since it is very computationally intensive I would like to optimise my code and improve the speed further. My main code is in MATLAB, but I am evaluating the function in C using the MEX functionality of MATLAB.

The mathematical problem is as follows: I have a matrix D with dimensions (M times N). Usually M is around 20,000 and N takes values around {10, 30, 144}.

[Definition of matrix D](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0J8wh.png)

Effectively, I need to obtain L column vector with dimensions (M times 1) defined as

[Definition of matrix L](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5N60v.png)

My C function looks like this:

```
void absolute_loss(double *D, double *L, mwSize cols, mwSize rows)
{

  double aux;
  int i;
  int j;
  int k;
  for (i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < rows; j++){
      aux = 0;
      for  (k = 0; k < cols; k++) {
        aux = aux + fabs(D[j + rows * k] - D[i + rows * k]);
      }
      L[i] = L[i] + aux;
    }
  }

  for (i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    L[i] /= rows;
  }
}
```

Comment: Start by making sure you are compiling with compiler optimizations enabled.

Comment: `int k_max = cols * rows; for ( k = 0; k < k_max; k += rows ) { aux = aux + fabs(D[j + k] - D[i + k]); }` would move the multiple `rows * k` multiplications out of the loop. Not sure if the compiler doesn't optimize that away already; hence, *measure, optimize, measure*.

Comment: Is *N* `rows` or `cols`, and is *M* `cols` or `rows`?

Comment: Stepping through a matrix by an increment such as `rows`, as you do with `j + rows * k`, is a recipe for thrashing cache. Swapping the loops on `j` and `k` might improve that, and there may be other opportunities to improve cache use. Details depend on the dimensions and the cache geometry.

Answer (score 2):

> How to speed up the computation of absolute loss matrix

- Enable compiler optimizations [@Jesper Juhl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76316325/how-to-speed-up-the-computation-of-absolute-loss-matrix-in-c/76316931#comment134576746_76316325).
- If able, use `float` types and `float` functions.  Sometimes up to 4x faster.  For me, 8% faster.
- Use `restrict` to let compiler know referenced data does not overlap.  Otherwise compiler must assume `L[i] = ...;` may change `D[]` and that prevents some optimizations.
- For referenced data, use `const` where able.
- Use consistent indexing types.
- Change index increment. [@DevSolar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76316325/how-to-speed-up-the-computation-of-absolute-loss-matrix-in-c/76316931#comment134576892_76316325)
- Index type: For me `size_t` and `unsigned` about the same.  `unsigned short` was 5% faster.

---

```
void absolute_loss(const float * restrict D, float * restrict L,
    mwSize cols, mwSize rows) {
  mwSize rows_cols = rows*cols;
  for (mwSize i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    for (mwSize j = 0; j < rows; j++){
      float aux = 0.0;
      for (mwSize k = 0; k < rows_cols; k += rows) {
        aux = aux + fabsf(D[j + k] - D[i + k]); // Note: fabsf
      }
      L[i] = L[i] + aux;
    }
  }
  for (mwSize i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    L[i] /= rows;
  }
}
```

---

Notes:

I'd expect the following, or the like, at the start of the function.

```
for (mwSize i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
  L[i] = 0.0;
}
```

Tip, rather than `rows, cols, i, j`, use `M, N, m, n` to match the formula.  I am not sure you have it right.

---

Candidate re-write that takes advantage of [variable length arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) and sample usage:

```
#include <math.h>

typedef unsigned short mwSize;

// Note re-ordered parameters.
void absolute_loss(mwSize m_rows, mwSize n_cols, //
    float D[restrict m_rows][n_cols], float L[restrict m_rows]) {

  for (mwSize ell = 0; ell < m_rows; ell++) {
    float ell_sum = 0.0;
    for (mwSize n = 0; n < n_cols; n++) {
      float d_ell_n = D[ell][n];
      for (mwSize m = 0; m < m_rows; m++) {
        ell_sum += fabsf(D[m][n] - d_ell_n);
      }
    }
    L[ell] = ell_sum / (float) m_rows;
  }
}

#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(void) {
  // Usually M is around 20,000 and N takes values around {10, 30, 144}.
  mwSize m_rows = (mwSize) (rand() % 1000 + (20000 - 1000));
  mwSize n_cols = (mwSize[3]) {10, 30, 144}[rand() % 3];

  float (*D)[m_rows][n_cols] = malloc(sizeof *D);
  assert(D);
  float (*L)[m_rows] = malloc(sizeof *L);
  assert(L);
  for (mwSize m = 0; m < m_rows; m++) {
    for (mwSize n = 0; n < n_cols; n++) {
      (*D)[m][n] = (float) (rand() % 1000 + 1);
    }
  }

  clock_t t0 = clock();
  absolute_loss(m_rows, n_cols, *D, *L);
  clock_t t1 = clock();
  // Print some of L
  for (mwSize ell = 0; ell < m_rows; ell++) {
    printf(" %-7g", (*L)[ell]);
    if (ell > 10) {
      printf("\n");
      break;
    }
  }
  printf("\n%g seconds.\n", (double) (t1 - t0) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
  free(L);
  free(D);
}
```

My time: 4.906 seconds.

Comment: Don't forget [SIMD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_instruction,_multiple_data) instructions via intrinsics.

Comment: Doesn't -march=native in most compilers take care of that?

Comment: Using `restrict` or not made little difference - hmmm.

Comment: Did you check the accuracy of the results as compared with those from the original function using doubles? When I re-wrote my function to use floats I got significant errors.

Comment: @SimonGoater Lower accuracy is expected with using `float` vs. `double`.  The significance of that is data dependent.  Unfortunately, OP has not provide sample data nor accuracy expectations. What we do know is the desire for more speed.  AFAIK, we may need to use `long double` to meet the unstated coding goals.

Answer (score 0):

You appear to have an unusual arrangement of rows and column with your matrix D. Your function accesses the data using indexes that jump around a lot which won't make best use of your memory cache. Rearranging the loops can make it process mostly contiguous elements improving performance significantly. On my computer, this runs almost 3 times faster than the function you posted for M=10000, N=30.

```
void absolute_loss2(const double * D, double * L, , mwSize cols, mwSize rows) {

  double Dtemp;
  int i, j, k, rowstimesk;
  for (i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    L[i] = 0.0;
  }
  for (i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    for  (k = 0; k < cols; k++) {
      rowstimesk = rows * k;
      Dtemp = D[i + rowstimesk];
      for (j = 0; j < rows; j++){
        L[j] += fabs(D[j + rowstimesk] - Dtemp);
      }
    }
  }

  for (i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    L[i] /= rows;
  }
}
```

You could probably build an even faster function with SIMD at the cost of simplicity, especially if you want to maintain portability. This wouldn't be a trivial re-factoring though.

Comment: "completes in about half of the time" --> is that the same with/without `restrict`?

Comment: Weirdly, it runs slower when I use restrict - about 45% vs 36% without, so I'm removing it. Adding const didn't make a noticeable difference but I'm adding it anyway.